# Not getting any output from ECG sensor AD8232

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, analogread

I am trying for the beginning to run a simple Arduino code in order to test the functionality of the ECG sensor. What I am getting on the output are some random values around 600 or around 200. 
I connected everything the same as in any tutorial about AD8232: 
GND -> GND, 3.3V -> 3.3V, L0+ -> digital pin 10, L0- -> digital pin 11, output -> analog pin A0. 
I placed the sensor pads on my body like in pictures (forming a triangle), but regardless of putting the electrodes or not, I always get the same floating signal.
Here is Arduino code:

```
int ecg;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(10,INPUT);
  pinMode(11,INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  if((digitalRead(10) == 1)||(digitalRead(11) == 1)){
    Serial.println('!');
  }
    else{
    // send the value of analog input 0:
    Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
    }
    //Wait for a bit to keep serial data from saturating
    delay(1);
}
```

When I run this code I get only "!" on the output, no matter where I put the electrodes on my body. When I comment "if" and "else" parts of the code and print directly only reading from the pin A0, I get those random floating values, like on the image.
[image: Random values from analog pin A0]

I also tried another custom built ECG sensor, but the results are the same. I haven't found the solution anywhere. It is not about the noise, because when I touch the metal box of my PC, I only reduce the values but there is still nothing on the output.

Comment: `I only reduce the values but there is still nothing on the output.`

Have you tried measuring using a laptop that isn't connected to AC? Not to mention, have you added large electrolytic capacitors to the 3.3V bus and made sure it can supply enough current for the sensor?

Comment: It is OK to accept your own answer as a solution to the problem. I think you get 15 rep for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I connected GND on the other half of the protoboard and there was no connection. I thought that the whole length of the protoboard is on the same potential for + and -, so GND wasn't connected. After connecting GND pin correctly, all worked perfectly.